# How can I get an item in the redux store by a key?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Suppose I have a reducer defined which returns an array of objects which contain keys like an id or something. What is the a redux way of getting /finding a certain object with a certain id in the array. The array itself can contain several arrays:

```
{ items:[id:1,...],cases:{...}}
```

What is the redux way to go to find a record/ node by id?

Answer (score 1):

The perfect redux way to store such a data would be to store them `byId` and `allIds` in an object in reducer.

In your case it would be:

```
{
  items: {
    byId  : {
      item1: {
        id     : 'item1',
        details: {}
      },
      item2: {
        id     : 'item2',
        details: {}
      }
    },
    allIds: [ 'item1', 'item2' ],
  },

  cases: {
    byId  : {
      case1: {
        id     : 'case1',
        details: {}
      },
      case2: {
        id     : 'case2',
        details: {}
      }
    },
    allIds: [ 'case1', 'case2' ],
  },
}
```

Ref: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html

This helps in keeping state normalized for both maintaining as well as using data.

This way makes it easier for iterating through all the array and render it or if we need to get any object just by it's id, then it'll be an `O(1)` operation, instead of iterating every time in complete array.

Comment: Best answer. This is how Redux wants you to normalize your state structure

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a library like *lodash*:

```
var fred = _.find(users, function(user) { return user.id === 1001; });
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markwill/pxpaoex3/)

It might be worth noting that it is seen as good practice to 'prefer objects over arrays' in the store (especially for large state trees); in this case you'd store your items in an object with (say) id as the key:

```
{
  '1000': { name: 'apple', price: 10 },
  '1001': { name: 'banana', price: 40 },
  '1002': { name: 'pear', price: 50 },
}
```

This makes selection easier, however you have to arrange the shape of the state when loading.

Answer (score -1):

there is no special way of doing this with redux. This is a plain JS task. I suppose you use react as well:

```
function mapStoreToProps(store) {
    function findMyInterestingThingy(result, key) {
         // assign anything you want to result
         return result;
    }

    return {
        myInterestingThingy: Object.keys(store).reduce(findMyInterestingThingy, {}) 
        // you dont really need to use reduce. you can have any logic you want
    };
}

export default connect(mapStoreToProps)(MyComponent)
```

regards